# Does "...attached to" simply mean "next to" OR does it mean "....an integral part of something as a whole"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

This is a sentence from a contact of sale of a property:

> **The purchaser has agreed to abandon the right of lane way attached to the property.**

I simply thought there is a lane way right next to the property, and it is a physical fact and it is not part of the property.

Still, I looked up **"attached"** and there is a meaning **"connected to"** with an example: *a house with an attached garage.*

Then I thought "*just like a garage is part of the property as a whole"* may be the lane way in the above sentence could also be a part of the property, which is why the seller wants to block the buyer to use the lane way.

So, I want to ask, does the word **"...attached to.."** simply refer to a physical fact meaning "...next to/adjacent to.."? Or does it mean that the laneway is an attachment of the property?

Comment: If this is part of a contract, *attached* may have a specific legal meaning.

Comment: I think there's a transcription error. Google finds just 4 instances of the sequence ["right of **lane** way".](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22right+of+lane+way%22&client=firefox-b-lm&sxsrf=AJOqlzVsKWV_YiRi8vlfRIgwA5yoon1rhw%3A1677178392528&ei=GLb3Y93gH8r1gQaB6K3ICg&ved=0ahUKEwjdzL6yqKz9AhXKesAKHQF0C6kQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22right+of+lane+way%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIJCAAQFhAeEPEEMgkIABAWEB4Q8QQyBggAEBYQHjIJCAAQFhAeEPEEMgkIABAWEB4Q8QQyBQgAEIYDMgUIABCGAzIFCAAQhgMyBQgAEIYDOgQIIxAnOgkIABAIEB4Q8QQ6BggAEAgQHkoECEEYAFAAWNgdYIcpaABwAXgAgAFpiAHIAZIBAzEuMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to interpret a legal text - either mistranscribed or not written by a native Anglophone lawyer in the first place. ELLINAL!

Comment: This is typical legal language in real estate. A right-of-way lane is correct, The right-of-way lane is attached i.e. is part of the property. Attachments can be man made or natural: https://study.com/academy/lesson/attachments-severance-in-real-estate-definitions-examples-laws.html And this legal English is fine. This question should not be closed.

Comment: I agree that it should be closed.  It is not a question of learning English, but a question of specific legal interpretation.  The OP should consult a legal expert on the proper interpretation of this easement. Or, if this just reading contracts for the purpose or studying English, then find a better source!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "attached" can be sued in several different senses. But in th given example:

> The purchaser has agreed to abandon the right of lane way attached to the property.

what is attached seems to be a **right**, not the physical lane. So I take this text  to mean that the right of use of the lane is, or has been associated with the property, that it, in a sense, comes with the ownership of the property. Of course it is no doubt also true that the physical lane is adjacent to the rest of the property.